# When I crop an image in Python, it returns 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
croppedImage = image.crop(200, 200, 200, 200)

window = Window(800, 800)

window.add(croppedImage)

window.wait()

window.close()

Error message: ParameterTypeError: Incorrect type for parameter 'graphic' : NoneType, expected GraphicalObject
```

Comment: What is the `window` object type?

Comment: Which Python are you talking about?  There's a lot of versions listed here that may or may not have any overlap.

Comment: lvc is correct, the crop function changes the image but it does not return anything.

Comment: Window() is basically Canvas(), so window's type is Window or Canvas on normal python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usually means that the `crop` function works by changing the image object it is applied to, instead of creating a new one - ie, you want to do this:

```
image.crop(200, 200, 200, 200)
window.add(image)
window.wait()
window.close()
```

Comment: It is confusing that the documentation lists: `im.crop(box) => image`